# show-all-if-ambiguous vs show-all-if-unmodified?

Tags: bash, readline, tab-completion

I couldn't find a clear explanation of the difference between the Readline options `show-all-if-ambiguous` and `show-all-if-unmodified`, and whether they affected different things or were mutually exclusive.  The official documentation is sparse on the subject.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the descriptions from the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html)

> **show-all-if-unmodified**
>
> This alters the default behavior of the completion functions in a fashion similar to show-all-if-ambiguous. If set to ‘on’, words which have more than one possible completion **without any possible partial completion** (the possible completions don’t share a common prefix) cause the matches to be listed immediately instead of ringing the bell. The default value is ‘off’.

This means that if any partial completions can be made then they will be filled in and all of the completions will not be shown.
If there is no partial completion to be made then all completions are shown.

> **show-all-if-ambiguous**
>
> This alters the default behavior of the completion functions. If set to ‘on’, words which have more than one possible completion cause the matches to be listed immediately instead of ringing the bell. The default value is ‘off’.

This means that the word will be partially completed up to the point where there is ambiguity **AND** will print all completions in one step.

---

#### Example

Say we have a files `abcd.txt` and `abce.txt`

Using
**show-all-if-unmodified**

typing

```
$ls a<tab>
```

will show

```
$ls abc
```

and pressing tab again (as there are no partial completions) would result in

```
$ls abc
abcd.txt abce.txt
$ls abc
```

Using
**show-all-if-ambiguous**

typing

```
ls a<tab>
```

will show

```
$ls a
abcd.txt abce.txt
$ls abc
```

So performs both actions in one step.

Also note that **show-all-if-ambiguous** overrides **show-all-if-unmodified** so if both are set to on then the behaviour will be that of the former.

Answer (score 2):

By default, readline will not print any possible completions if there is more than one possible completion.  Additionally, if all possible completions share a common prefix, that common prefix is inserted.

The two options discussed change readline's behavior:

- **`show-all-if-ambiguous`** will cause readline to print possible completions after the first <kbd>Tab</kbd> press, even if there is more than one.
- **`show-all-if-unmodified`** will do the same, *except for the case when all completions share a common prefix*.

---

An example:

Let's say we have two possible completion matches, and they share a common prefix.  For example, in an empty directory, run:

```
touch ___1 ___2
```

Now, type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

If we have **`show-all-if-ambiguous`** turned on, the screen will look like:

```
$ :
___1  ___2
$ : ___
```

But if we have only **`show-all-if-unmodified`** turned on, the screen will look like:

```
$ : ___
```

Note that this point, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will trigger the display of possible completions in either case.  However, were we to have *neither* of the above options turned on, nothing would happen and we would have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once more to get the listing.